# Developing independently from UI framework

Tags: c#

I'm trying to organize my code flexible. So my application makes heavy use of interfaces. In my controller class I want to start the webcam preview on a certain control in the view. Implementations of ClientView and WebcamPreview rely on each other. So there is one specific WebcamPreview for WinForms and one for WPF. I ended with 2 possible ways:

**Option 1:**

Pros: Generics

Cons: Generic declarations bubble up to the top controller class, and I need to declare at least 3 generics in it. (Maybe I'm doing something wrong?)

```
interface IClientView<TSelf>
{
    TSelf SelfControl { get; }
}

interface IWebcamPreview<TSelf>
{
    void Start(TSelf selfControl);
}
```

**Option 2:**

Pros: Avoids to much generics

Cons: Directives; will compile different assemblies for WPF and WinForms

```
interface IClientView
{
#if WPF
    ControlBase SelfControl { get; }
#else // WinForms
    PictureBox SelfControl { get; }
#endif
}

interface IWebcamPreview
{
    // analog
}
```

So how do I organize my code in order to support different UI frameworks?

Comment: By showing your solutions only I think you've abstracted a little far away from your original problem.  I *think* your `IWebcamPreview` design might be... a bit upside-down, for want of a better word.  An Ideal solution wouldn't rely AT ALL on the control that was attached to it - it would - perhaps - provide a feed that you could attach to from other controls regardless of whether they are WPF or Winforms...?

Comment: Just as an example: I use DirectShow to preview (and capture) the webcam image. DirectShow needs the Handle (IntPtr) of the control where it should draw the preview. So how should I design it to be decoupled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 3:**

```
abstract class AbstractControl { }

class WinFormsControl : AbstractControl { }

class WpfControl : AbstractControl { }

interface IClientView
{
   AbstractControl SelfControl { get; }
}
```

Comment: I need to pass non-custom controls like PictureBox and <whatever it is in WPF>. So this wouldn't work, or do I miss something?

Comment: This would easily work if your concrete classes can return controls or even better - if you provide an adapter to convert these to controls. The idea was only to show that you have other options when it comes to class structure.

Comment: So `WinFormsControl` and `WPFControl` would be some kind of container(?) for the original controls?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 is the way to go.  Option 2 will get very busy with directives very quickly.  If one day, you find yourself, in addition to WPF and Winform, have to do for Windows Phone, and Web app, you'll have to touch lots of code to add new #elif directives.  Code will not be too pleasant to look at at that point.  With option 1 and some good organizations i.e., the WPF goes into 1 assembly, the Winform another, future addition such as for Windows Phone may not require even a recompile of existing code.  If it does, maybe very minimal.

Comment: So you would argue that it's unavoidable to have many generics bubble up the line?